# after Git OverWrite master branch with another branch, did all history get deleted for master branch ?

Tags: git, github, git-branch

after Git OverWrite master branch with another branch, did all history get deleted for master branch ?

I want to overwrite another branch with master branch but same time I wanted to keep all commit history for master, is that possible?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by “overwrite”? and also show any commands you used with their output?

Comment: I did not use any command yet. I was looking for some command that replaces my entire master code with my other branch. I have some corrupt code in master which I cannot remove manually.